# How to get website url which user is opening or viewing?

Tags: android

I want to create an app which can get the website URL which user is opening or viewing; not only the browser history becuse I just want to get the URL which is in browser pages.

Answer (score 0):

use WebViewClient to get url which user is opening in onPageStarted, that code is work

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webset=webView.getSettings();

webset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Log.i("chauster", "url = "+url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
            HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view, handler, host, realm);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedLoginRequest(WebView view, String realm,
            String account, String args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceivedLoginRequest(view, realm, account, args);
    }

});
webView.loadUrl(Url);
```

Comment: actually, i want to monitor the default or thrid party browser.Not my own app.

Answer (score 0):

In your webView -

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        String webUrl = webView.getUrl(); //gets the current url
        Log.i("chauster", "url = "+url);  //logs the current url
    }
}
```

See Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl()

Comment: actually, i want to monitor the default or thrid party browser.

Comment: As much I know it should not be possible. If yes, woul let you kowl